# How to show text that moves along in scrollbar inside RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sectionindexer

I would like to design by alphabetically section and along with it bubble which indicated text (alphabet) scrolling.

I have search about same but no any solid implementation found for this UI.

Does **sectionIndexer** will help, and yes then how?

**Note: Please don't recommend any library for it**

[image: screenshot]